# how to get data from 3 collections in mongodb using node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

> I have the below collections in mongodb

```
db.orders.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc69ad493297eade15bacb7"), "item" : "card", "qty" : 15, "user_mob" : 8220097 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc69adf93297eade15bacb8"), "item" : "card1", "qty" : 11, "user_mob" : 8220097 }

db.items.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc69ba493297eade15bacbc"), "item" : "card1", "color" : "blue", "weight" : "50g" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc69bb793297eade15bacbd"), "item" : "card", "color" : "yellow", "weight" : "60g" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc69bd193297eade15bacbe"), "item" : "ball", "color" : "multi color", "weight" : "140g" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc69be793297eade15bacbf"), "item" : "footer", "color" : "Black", "weight" : "340g" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc69c0c93297eade15bacc0"), "item" : "caps", "color" : "multi color", "weight" : "250g" }

db.users_nippon.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cadf1d9b0a2d18bdc6de90a"), "name" : "hariharan", "mobile_no" : "8220097", "role_id" : "2", "language_code" : "ml", "encrypted_password" : "password_Passw0rd", "is_salesman" : "true", "is_mobile" : "true" }
```

And I write code in node js to fetch data from all the above tables.
The code is...

```
db.collection('users_nippon').aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                   from: "orders",
                   localField: "mobile_no",
                   foreignField: "user_mob",
                   as: "orders_data"
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$orders_data"
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "items",
                    localField: "item",
                    foreignField: "item",
                    as: "items_data"
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$items_data"
            }
        ]).toArray(function(err, list) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
            res.send(JSON.stringify(list));
            });
```

There is something went wrong. It returns empty (**[ ]**).

so , please help me to fix this issue... Thanks in advance.

**Below code is the sample for The output which i want**

```
[
{
    "_id": "5cc67e439c26e35a70fddfd5",
    "name": "hariharan",
    "mobile_no": "8220097",
    "role_id": "2",
    "language_code": "ml",
    "encrypted_password": "password_Passw0rd",
    "is_salesman": "true",
    "is_mobile": "true",
    "orders_data": {
        "_id": "5cc6ebe9f4c1d9080b93b013",
        "item": "card",
        "qty": 15,
        "user_mob": "8220097",
        "items_data": {
                "_id": "5cc69bb793297eade15bacbd",
                "item": "card",
                "color": "yellow",
                "weight": "60g"
          }
    }

}]
```

Comment: are you getting null on this `console.log(JSON.stringify(list));` ?

Comment: no. I getting empty array [ ]

Comment: Remove `JSON.Stringify` and two `$unwind` stages from the above code and check the response.

Comment: it returns some data. but , the structure of the return data not in format.   [
    {
        "_id": "5cadf1d9b0a2d18bdc6de90a",
        "name": "hariharan",
        "mobile_no": "8220097",
        "role_id": "2",
        "language_code": "ml",
        "encrypted_password": "password_Passw0rd",
        "is_salesman": "true",
        "is_mobile": "true",
        "orders_data": [],
        "items_data": []
    }
   }

Comment: Are your collections linked, can you show us ur users_nippon model

Comment: @noitse I don't know collections linking. how can i link 3 collections? please give me some example..

Comment: Sry just saw you are not using ObjectId, so ref won't have any effect. But answer bellow is right, you are not using same types for your fields

Comment: guys please give me up votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change data-type of `mobile_no` in `users_nippon` collection from `string` to `NumberLong` otherwise `$lookup` will not work. After correcting it, now you can use below aggregation query to get your desired result in the same format you want.

```
db.collection('users_nippon').aggregate([

        {
            $lookup: {
              from: "orders",
              localField: "mobile_no",
              foreignField: "user_mob",
              as: "orders_data"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$orders_data"
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "items",
                localField: "orders_data.item",
                foreignField: "item",
                as: "orders_data.items_data"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$orders_data.items_data"
        }
    ]).toArray(function(err, list) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
        res.send(JSON.stringify(list));
        });
```

this is the tested and working solution.

Comment: now it's working bro. Thanks for your answer. You save me. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issues in your query:

1. The field `user_mob` (orders schema) is a `Number` while `mobile_no` (user_nippon schema) is a `String` therefore the lookup cannot be made. You might want to use the same type for those fields.
2. The second `lookup` is incorrect. the first `lookup` and `unwind` returns your `item` element inside the `orders_data` element so the `localField` of this `lookup` should be changed to: `orders_data.item`

So after you change both `user_mob` and `mobile_no` to have matching types your query would look like this:

```
db.collection('users_nippon').aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                   from: "orders",
                   localField: "mobile_no",
                   foreignField: "user_mob",
                   as: "orders_data"
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$orders_data"
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "items",
                    localField: "orders_data.item",
                    foreignField: "item",
                    as: "items_data"
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$items_data"
            }
        ]).toArray(function(err, list) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
            res.send(JSON.stringify(list));
            });
```

Comment: Your code is useful.. it give me some output. but i need the output in different Json format.. please check the question for the output format. Thank you